# limitToLast: 1 query returning everything

Tags: angular, angularfire2

I'm using AngularFire2 and just can't get the queries part down. "limitToLast: 1" is returning everything instead of just my most recent entry. I need a way to number my jobs sequentially, and I am trying to get the most recent jobID (4) so I can add+1 and make the next one 5.

```
job: FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;
test: any;

constructor(af: AngularFire) {
    this.job = af.database.object('/jobs/', {
        query:{ limitToLast: 1 }
    });
};

createNewJob(){
    this.job.subscribe(snap => {
        this.test = snap;
    });
}
```

Instead of outputting my single most recent entry I get everything:

```
[ null, 
        { "customer": "Heather D", "description": "Work needs to be done" },
        { "customer": "Quick G", "description": "Unclog toilet" },
        { "customer": "Justin S", "description": "Do everything for everyone" }
        { "customer": "Jeff F", "description": "Ikea furniture" }
]
```

HTML

```
<button (click)="createNewJob()"> Create </button>
{{ test |  json }}
```

Here's my structure

```
ROOT
    jobs
        1
            customer: "Heather D"
            description: "Work needs to be done"
        2
            customer: "Quick G"
            description: "Unclog toilet"
        3
            customer: "Justin S"
            description: "Do everything for everyone"
        4
            customer: "Jeff F"
            description: "Ikea furniture"
```

UPDATE 1:

Still having the same problem, but I feel like this is a step in the right direction. Correct me if I'm wrong. I've given my jobs a unique ID now, which seems redundant to me, but the new structure looks like this:

```
ROOT
    jobs
        1
            customer: "Heather D"
            description: "Work needs to be done"
            id: 1
        2
            customer: "Quick G"
            description: "Unclog toilet"
            id: 2
        3
            customer: "Justin S"
            description: "Do everything for everyone"
            id: 3
        4
            customer: "Jeff F"
            description: "Ikea furniture"
            id: 4
```

and then I changed my query:

```
query:{ orderByChild: 'id', limitToLast: 1 }
```

Same results, still not limiting to just one job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `object` rather than `list`. The `query` options are ignored when `object` is used. That is, you should use something like this:

```js
job: FirebaseListObservable<any>;
test: any;

constructor(af: AngularFire) {
    this.job = af.database.list('/jobs/', {
        query:{ limitToLast: 1 }
    });
};
```

The `FirebaseListObservable` should emit an array containing the last job.

However, rather than reading and then incrementing the last job ID, it would be safer to use the `FirebaseListObservable` instance's [`push`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/3-retrieving-data-as-lists.md#api-summary) method. See also [Saving Lists of Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#section-push):

> When working with lists of data `push()` ensures a unique and chronological key. You may be tempted to use transactions instead to generate your own keys, but push is a far better choice. Transactions are slower and more complex. They require one or more round trips to the server. A key generated by `push()` on the client works while offline and is optimized for performance.

Comment: Oh, I'll try with lists and let you know! As for push(), I would like to use that, but I still do need my jobs to have Job ID's that are short enough to read to customers. (IE: Job ID 7051354) Can push do that? And are you saying I shouldn't at all use transactions, or would transactions be my only option for doing that?

Comment: It worked! I got one result back! Finally! lol.  Now I have a small side effect with the results though. query:{orderByChild: 'id', limitToFirst: 1} gave me my third result. Not first or last. I changed it to query:{ limitToLast: 1} and it worked.... but.... anyone know why that would give me a result in the middle of my list?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you sort your records in descending order of job id and limit it to first one ? this will get you the last record

Comment: I can't seem to find any docs on that, would that look something like orderByChild: 'descending' ?

Comment: I just ran { query: [ 'orderByChild', { limitToFirst: 1 } ] } just to test some examples I saw online, and it returned the whole list as well. I don't know if that's valid code, but it didn't give error, so I guess it is? lol. Either way, still stuck at my original issue for like 6hrs now :(